Laptop wont boot on replacement battery, but works fine when the adapter is connected?
We have a Lenovo Y50-70 gaming laptop. The original battery went dead, so we bought new battery from Green Cell.
But the problem is that laptop cannot boot to windows on battery. It shuts down on windows boot screen. Once connected to power outlet it boots and we can disconnect from power, and the battery works fine.
Should we try battery from different manufacturer? Replacing the CMOS battery? or something else?

You seem to have found the issue: startup current need is greater than while running. The battery seems to be too weak to boot.
There are a few possibilities:

The battery as shipped is not fully charged. Let it charge for a day or so and try again.
The battery charging parameters in the Lenovo needs to be reset. For many PC's, this requires the following:

Shut all applications and shut down completely, e.g., shutdown /s /f.
Unplug the power supply.
Disconnect the battery (yes, that's a nuisance with an internal battery).
Hold down the power button for 30 seconds or so.
Replace the battery.
Plug in he power supply and let charge a day.


The battery is defective. Return it for a replacement.

The clock cell has nothing to do with boot, AFAIK. You could test it, and if <3 VDC while in place, remove and replace it.



The battery was charged to 100%, still same happens.


Haven't tried 30 seconds power button, but maybe reseting BIOS can help?


We ordered second identical battery from Green Cell. Same problem. Maybe it is not defective battery, but incompatible parameters?


